# How to use class named "Case"?

Tags: php

I have a model class named `Case` in namespace `App`. When I try to `use` it I get:

> syntax error, unexpected 'Case' (T_CASE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or '{'

Source code, error is on the line with `use App\Case`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Case;
use App\Http\Requests\CaseStoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\CaseUpdateRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CaseController extends Controller {
/* ... */
}
```

How to escape class name in `use` declaration?

I'm using PHP 7.4.4 and framework Laravel 7.

Comment: Maybe `use App\Case as CaseModel;`?

Comment: @mare96, I tried, it didn't change anything.

Comment: you can't, its a reserved word https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`case` is a reserved keyword in PHP (https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php), so you cannot use it as a class name.